# How to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 n\ln(1+{1\over n\sqrt x})\ dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 n\ln(1+{1\over n\sqrt x})\ dx$$

Can I apply monotonic convergence theorem?

My work is that
$$\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}nln(1+{1\over n\sqrt x})dx$$
$$\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_1^{1+{1\over n\sqrt x}}1/ydy$$
Let $$y=1+{1\over n\sqrt t}$$
then dy=1/n(-t^(-3/2))dt

$$\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^x{1\over 1+{1\over n\sqrt t}}(-1){1\over2}t^{-3/2}dt$$
Apply monotonic theorem

$$\int_0^1x^{-1/2}dx=2$$

Answer (score 8):

We can actually apply dominated convergence here (perhaps also monotone, but dominated is easier to use in this case).  Using the inequality $\log(1+x) \leq x$, we can bound the integrand pointwise
$$
n\log(1+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{x}}) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}.
$$
Since $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx < \infty$, we can safely apply dominated convergence to see that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 n\log(1+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{x}})\,dx
= \int_0^1 \lim_{n\to\infty} n\log(1+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{x}})\,dx
= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx.
$$
And this integral is simple to evaluate, 
$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = \left.2\sqrt{x}\right|_0^1 = 2.
$$

Comment: Does my work also right?

Comment: From what I understand, it seems you have a way to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\log(1+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{x}}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.  I believe your proof of that limit is correct.  In my answer I am more concerned with the validity of moving the limit inside of the integral, which as you see is not difficult to justify.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!